# How to apply a function to all divs on a page

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have multiple divs on a page and I want to add functionality to all of them without making each have unique id's and rewriting the functions for each one. How would I do this? So far I have this:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w27tt8jy/)

```
<div id="target">text</div>
<br>
<div id="target">text</div>
<br>
<div id="target">text</div>
<br>
<div id="target">text</div>
<br>
<div id="target">text</div>

<script>
var elem = document.getElementById("target");
elem.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
elem.style.color = "red";
});

elem.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
elem.style.color = "black";
});
</script>

<style>
#target {
background-color: blue;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Keep a class instead of a id

Comment: First up: ids need to be unique - you have 4 divs with the same id. You might want to change that to class='target'. Then you can use document.querySelectorAll(".target") then loop through each one applying the event handler. https://jsfiddle.net/w27tt8jy/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes instead of IDs and then you could use this.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".listentome");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    this.style.color = "red";
  });
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0L866dyy/)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `id` to `class` and change the JS and CSS codes like this:

In Jquery:

```
$(".target").each(function(){
  var ele = $(this);
  $(this).on("mouseenter",function(){
    ele.css("color","red");
  });
  $(this).on("mouseenter",function(){
    ele.css("color","black");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.target {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: You cannot listen to the NodeList returned from `querySelectorAll` in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `class` instead of `id`

```
<div id="target">text</div>
```

Also you have to use event delegation if you'd to add one event listener

```
document.body.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'target'){
    e.target.style.color = "red";
  }
});
```

Same strategy for `mouseleave`.

```
document.body.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'target'){
    e.target.style.color = "black";
  }
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Html's id is unique only one.
so you can use getElementByTagName alternative getElementById.

below is code

```
<script>
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
    var obj = elem[i];
    obj.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
        this.style.color = "red";
});

obj.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    this.style.color = "black";
});
}
</script>
```

bye.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the capture mode in linking the listener.
Firstly.
It can be done in the manner in which you need it
The way in which you can accomplish what you need would be:
Create a masked or a parent element for all your items:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="target">text1</div>
    <br>
    <div class="target">text2</div>
    <br>
    <div class="target">text3</div>
    <br>
    <div class="target">text4</div>
    <br>
    <div class="target">text5</div> 
</div>
```

Then we need to select the parent element:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("container");
```

Then we need to add two listeners to that element:

```
elem.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
    if(e.target.className === "target"){
        e.toElement.style.color = "red";
    }
}, true);

elem.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e){
    if(e.target.className === "target"){
        e.fromElement.style.color = "black";
    }
}, true);
```

It must enable the capture mode, since by default the W3C specification listeners come with false or bubbling mode is activated.
Thus when the event is executed in this case "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" on the parent element that execute on this element and all internal elements, using capture type.

```
elem.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
    if(e.target.className === "target"){
        e.toElement.style.color = "red";
    }
/* Here */
}, true);
```

Then we have to get the current div element to which the mouse is over.

```
if(e.target.className === "target")
```

Because as the listener is bound to the parent element will also run in this, so you only need the child elements with the class "target".

For further reading:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target